# Show that $\{(X_{n},X_{n+1})\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov Chain where $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Show that $\{(X_{n},X_{n+1})\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov Chain where $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov Chain.

**Remark:** We know that $\mathbb{P}(A|\emptyset)$ is undefined, I am right?
This fact is important in my attempt and is what motivates this post.

**My attempt:** We define $Y_{n}:=(X_{n},X_{n+1})$, then we are going to verify if we have the Markov property. On the one hand, we know that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=(i,j)\:|\:Y_{n-1}=(i_{n-1},j_{n-1})]&=\mathbb{P}[X_{n}=i,X_{n+1}=j\:|\:X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n}=j_{n-1}]\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0 &\mbox{ if }i\neq j_{n-1}\\ p_{ij} &\mbox{ if } i=j_{n-1}. \end{array}\right.
\end{align}
where $P$ is transition matrix of $\{X_{n}\}_{n\geq 0}$. On the other hand, we have

\begin{align}
&\mathbb{P}[Y_{n}=(i,j)\:|\:Y_{0}=(i_{0},j_{0}),\ldots,Y_{n-2}=(i_{n-2},j_{n-2}),Y_{n-1}=(i_{n-1},j_{n-1})]\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left[X_{n}=i,X_{n+1}=j\:|\:X_{0}=i_{0},X_{1}=j_{0},\ldots,X_{n-2}=i_{n-2},X_{n-1}=j_{n-2},X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},X_{n}=j_{n-1}\right]\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\mbox{undefined} & \mbox{if }\exists k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-2\}\mbox{ such that }j_{k}\neq i_{k+1}\\ 0 & \mbox{if }\forall k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-2\}\mbox{ such that }j_{k}=i_{k+1} \mbox{ and }j_{n-1}\neq i\\ p_{ij} & \mbox{if }\forall k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-2\}\mbox{ such that }j_{k}=i_{k+1} \mbox{ and }j_{n-1}= i \end{array}\right.
\end{align}
***My problem is in the undefined case, this is making me think that this chain is not a Markov chain. What do you think about this?***

This exercise appears in [Adventures in Stochastic Processes; Resnick, Sidney I.](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780817635916)

Comment: Note that $$\mathbb P((X_{n+1},X_n) = (i',j') \mid (X_n,X_{n-1})=(i,j) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb P(X_1 = i' \mid X_0 = i),& i=j'\\
0,& i\ne j'.
\end{cases} $$

Comment: @Math1000 I do not understand your comment, in my attempt I calculate what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, in the definition of a Markov chain (with state space $\mathbb N$),
we require the equality
$$
\mathbb P\left(X_n=j\mid X_{n-1}=i,X_{k}=i_k,0\leqslant k\leqslant n-2\right)=\mathbb P\left(X_n=j\mid X_{n-1}=i\right)
$$
to hold for each $i$, $i_1,\dots,i_{n-2}$ such that the event $A:=\{X_{n-1}=i,X_{k}=i_k,0\leqslant k\leqslant n-2\}$ has a positive probability. This is possible that the previously event $A$ has probability zero, for example if $i_1$ and $i_2$ are two states which do not communicate. So an undefined case may also hold for Markov chains which are not defined as a vector like $(X_n,X_{n+1})$ hence this "issue" (quote mark because it is not really one) is not specific to this problem.